# View PDF in browser rather than download

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf

There are meetings on this website and each meeting has a PDF attached showing the meeting minutes. The next meeting that takes place dynamically collects this attached PDF and allows for a download as the previous minutes. This is all working perfectly, however, when clicking the link for the previous minutes it always opens up a save as box. I was wondering how to get this to just display in the browser (assuming the user has a PDF viewer enabled)?

Here is the function from the controller:

```
public function current_pdf($id = null, $pdf = null) {
$this->loadModel('Document');
$document = $this->Document->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Document.dir', 'Document.url')
        ));
$request_pdf = $this->Meeting->read(null, $id);

if ($pdf == 'current') {
  $file = $document[$request_pdf['Meeting']['minutes']];
  if (!empty($file)) {
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize(WWW_ROOT . 'files/document/url/' . $request_pdf['Meeting']['minutes'] . '/' . $file));
    flush(); // this doesn't really matter.

    $fp = fopen(WWW_ROOT . 'files/document/url/' . $request_pdf['Meeting']['minutes'] . '/' . $file, "r");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
      echo fread($fp, 65536);
      flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
    }
    fclose($fp);
    //echo WWW_ROOT.'files/document/url/pdf/'.$file; die;
    //readfile(WWW_ROOT.'files/document/url/pdf/'.$file);
    exit;
  }
  $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'meetings', 'action' => 'view/' . $id));
} else {
  $file = $request_pdf['Meeting']['current_minutes'];
  if (!empty($file)) {
    //echo filesize(WWW_ROOT.'files/document/url/pdf/'.$file); die;
    /* header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
      header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
      header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . urlencode(basename($file)));
      // header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
      header('Pragma: public');
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
      ob_clean();
      flush(); */

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize(WWW_ROOT . 'files/document/url/pdf/' . $file));
    flush(); // this doesn't really matter.

    $fp = fopen(WWW_ROOT . 'files/document/url/pdf/' . $file, "r");
    while (!feof($fp)) {
      echo fread($fp, 65536);
      flush(); // this is essential for large downloads
    }
    fclose($fp);
    //echo WWW_ROOT.'files/document/url/pdf/'.$file; die;
    //readfile(WWW_ROOT.'files/document/url/pdf/'.$file);
    exit;
  }
  $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'meetings', 'action' => 'view/' . $id));
}
```

}

And here is the link in the view:

`<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Download Previous Minutes'), array('controller' => 'meetings', 'action' => 'current_pdf', $download, 'current')); ?>`

I have tried removing the header("Content-Type...") lines of code and changing attachment in `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));` to inline. This stopped the save as pop-up but displayed a load of spurious code in the browser instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm currently very confused.

Comment: Could you change the disposition to inline and also serve a type of application/pdf?

Comment: CakePHP 2.3 and older have a class MediaView will attempt to display the file if you have download set to false.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/media-view.html  In CakePHP 2.4, MediaView has been deprecated for sendFile, which I have never used, but I think could also display pdfs.  You may want to make use of route's parseExtension feature.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions

Comment: That was perfect halfer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is as simple as removing this line in your code:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($file));
```

This line will server up the file as a download, and not display the content in the browser.

I hope that helps!

Comment: It's better to explicitly change the disposition type to `inline` and change the content type to `application/pdf`, just like @halfer mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Yep, halfer hit the nail on the head. Thank you :)